# Applications of propositional logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm working on this propositional logic question and I did not understand the book answer at all. The book says the hostess knows to bring back two drinks for the first two professors.

> When three professors are seated in a restaurant, the hostess ask them, "*Does everyone want coffee?*" The first professor says, "*I do not know.*"  The second professor then says, "*I do not know.*" Finally, the third professor says, "*No, not everyone wants coffee.*" The hostess comes back and gives coffee to the professors who want it.  How did she figure out who wanted coffee?

Comment: What are you thoughts? You have to have *some* initial thoughts on how to approach this.

Comment: @MikePierce  Are the best approaches when dealing with these problems just to stick with the truth tables.

Comment: Truth tables are a bit brutish (it'll work, but it will take a while). For this problem, I would start to consider the different cases in your head. Think to yourself, "*Suppose that the first professor doesn't want coffee. What can he say to the waitress? What can he say if he does want coffee? ...*". This should be insightful.

Comment: @user1238097 I'd like to see a truth table for this scenario...

Answer (score 8):

Suppose that the first professor did *not* want coffee. Is it still possible that everyone wants coffee?

Comment: This is a better answer than the lengthy explanation I was going to type up.

Comment: @Gregory I see what you mean.